# MySQL Workbench EER/ERD Diagram - graphical relationships

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, erd

I'm using MySQL Workbench to build an EER (basically ERD) diagram for a client. I'm wondering if there are any settings (or plugins) available which align relationships to table columns?

At the moment my workbench is simply centering relationships between tables, but I'd like them to actually point to the columns within the tables (fk <--> pk).

[image: Example Image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By selecting `Model -> Relationship Notation -> Connect to Columns` you can change the display from the default:

[image]

to the way you expect it:

[image]